# Is there any benefit to cryptically naming your form fields?

Tags: forms

Is there any security benefit to using cryptic names for your form fields like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_jw58dplem42pd45r'])){$submit = $_POST["submit_jw58dplem42pd45r"];} else {$submit ="";}
if (isset($_POST['txt_textbox_f48yjdp429plwdhp'])){$txt_textbox = $_POST["txt_textbox_f48yjdp429plwdhp"];} else {$txt_textbox ="";}

if ($submit=="submit"){

echo "$txt_textbox";

}

echo "<form method='post'>" 
. "<input type='text' name='txt_textbox_f48yjdp429plwdhp' size='45' maxlength='45'       value='Text Value Here'>" 
. "<input type='hidden' name='submit_jw58dplem42pd45r' value='submit'>" 
. "<input type='submit' value=' Submit '>" 
. "</form>";
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

Security through obfuscation doesn't work, in this case there's absolutely no benefit whatsoever, you're just complicating things for no reason. The sites visitors still need to know what information to input, those indicators would be trivial to find using a bot (not that they are needed).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think so.  I had this idea a while back and stopped doing it because it seemed pointless.  I'm going through all my old code trying to put together a snippet library and I'll trash this bad idea.